# SendNotifyMessage to control Windows monitor causes reordering of IE tabs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've got a technical question with sending message in Windows in order to turn monitor on using `winapi` functions.

When I send message like this :

```
SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST,WM_SYSCOMMAND,SC_MONITORPOWER,-1)
```

the tabs in `Internet Explorer` are moved. This is the problem that I have been tackling for three days, and as of yet have not found a solution. Can you guys explain me why the tabs in IE move when I send that message ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you are sending that message. That's a message that the system sends, and you respond to. You are not meant to send it.

Comment: I need to send this message in order to turn  my monitor or when he is sleeping or even when he's not.

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors -> too localized.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that what happens is this:

1. You have multiple monitors.
2. The message arrives at IE that its monitor is being turned off.
3. IE responds to this by moving itself to one of the remaining monitors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the power to the monitor by sending SC_MONITORPOWER, you can simply do so by just sending this message to your own program itself (the one that is doing the message sending). This message will finally filter down to the DefWindowProc and will be handled by the OS.

```
PostMessage(m_hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, -1);
```

Broadcast such system message by user program may cause unexpected complication as all applications is forced to response to it and process the message in their own way multiple times.

refer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/13/629451.aspx